# No exception log output in excepiton.log file in pyramid project with plugin pyramid_exclog under uwsgi

Tags: python, logging, pyramid, uwsgi

I use uwsgi to deploy my pyramid project. and also use pyramid_exclog to catch exception log which is expected to logto the file exception.log . But all the log info(include the exception log) was output to the file 'project.log' which was setted in the section of [uwsgi], file production.ini

```
[uwsgi]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
logto = /var/log/project.log
```

I need your help to make exception info output to the file of exception.log instead of project.log
I use the 'pserve' command to start up my project, everything works well.
So how to deploy the pyramid_exclog under uwsgi.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: make exception info output to the file of exception.log instead of project.log

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. I've tried the `--ini-paste-logged` option, but that requires Paste. I'm running under Python 3.3 and Paste hasn't been updated for Python 3, so that wasn't going to work for me.

What I came up with was to create my own WSGI application file like so (file named `production.wsgi`):

```
import configparser
import logging.config

from myapp import main

ini_path = 'production.ini'

# Set up logging
logging.config.fileConfig(ini_path)

# Parse config and create WSGI app
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(ini_path)

# First argument is default config values, second argument are the settings
# from the app:main section
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/startup.html
application = main(config['DEFAULT'], **config['app:main'])
```

Then in my `production.ini` file I have the following `[uwsgi]` section:

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = %d/production.wsgi
chdir = %d
http-socket = :29999
enable-threads = true
master = true
processes = 1
```

Instead of starting it with `--ini-paste` or `--ini-paste-logged`, I just start it with `--ini`:

```
/usr/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/local/myapp/production.ini
```

(uWSGI is actually installed into my app's virtual environment.)

Answer (score 1):

pyramid_exclog uses the standard python logging module. Thus you need to ensure that uwsgi is parsing logging configuration from your ini when running your application. I think this involves invoking your app with `--ini-paste-logged` or some such under uWSGI. Also, ensure you actually setup logging as mentioned in the pyramid_exclog documentation.

Comment: I use --ini-paste which will contain uwsgi section in ini file. And I've tried --ini-paste-logged, the exception info still logto the project.log file.  I use the 'pserve' command to start up my project, everything works well

Comment: sounds to me like you don't have logging setup correctly. does it work when you don't use uwsgi?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it. Found this on irc log

First, make sure you set it up properly like described [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_exclog/en/latest/index.html)

Then set the logging manually in your app

```
from pyramid.paster import setup_logging

# somewhere in your main app
setup_logging('your-settings.ini')
```

I do not know if there is side effects doing this but so far it works