# Cannot get logging to work when running Pyramid app with uwsgi

Tags: python, logging, pyramid, uwsgi

I have a Pyramid application, which works fine, when started via `pserve` or via `uwsgi`. When started via `pserve`, my logging setup works fine, but not when started via `uwsgi`. The `uwsgi` section of my paster ini looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:3099
master = True
processes = 1
virtualenv = /opt/data/virtualenvs/some_virtual_env
paste = config:%p
paste-logger = True
buffer-size = 65535
```

I found of course [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159713/logging-not-working-when-running-pyramid-app-under-uwsgi-in-emperor-mode) and also tried to configure the logger like this:

```
paste-logger = %p
```

But is does not work. My logging config is using an absolute path and the target folder of the log file allows reading and writing for everybody. I wonder a little bit about how to specify `paste-logger`, because it has no argument according to the [documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html?highlight=paste#paste-logger).

The command line configuration for upstart is defined like this:

```
exec uwsgi --master --die-on-term --emperor /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled
```

No custom log files are created and in the uwsgi log I don't see any helpful messages or errors. Any help how to get logging working or to debug the problem would be very appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at this answer or its parallel answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21503965/118903

Answer (score 3):

This is not exactly what you asked about, but the following works for me on Ubuntu.

I use default logging configuration provided by Pyramid templates, which streams logs into stderr:

```
# Begin logging configuration

[loggers]
keys = root, myapp

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_myapp]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = myapp

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s

# End logging configuration
```

Each uWSGI application in Ubuntu has its own config file, which should be placed in
/etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/ directory. Here myapp.ini for example:

```
[uwsgi]
plugin = python
virtualenv = /path/to/myapp/virutalenv
paste = config:/path/to/myapp/config.ini
```

So when I run application using pserve command I will get logs in console. When I run it using uWSGI, uWSGI will create output logs into /var/log/uwsgi/app/myapp.log

**UPDATE**

I just dug around uWSGI configs and found a place, where log file location is set up. uWSGI init.d scripts use [daemonize](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#daemonize) argument:

```
--daemonize "/var/log/uwsgi/${CONFNAMESPACE}/${CONFNAME}.log"
```

**UPDATE 2**

It may be helpful in your case to explicitly setup logging in your application:

```
from pyramid.paster import setup_logging

setup_logging("/path/to/config.ini")
```

Comment: This does not help, because I'll have to send different loggers to different log files. But just curious: Where is `/var/log/uwsgi/app/myapp.log` configured?

Comment: UPDATE 2 above saved me a headache, added that line to the script that launched the cheroot server and finally the logs started coming through.